# After splash screen, display white screen long time after killing the application and launching again in ionic ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an ionic application with both the platforms in android and iOS. The problem is that when the iOS application is launched for the first time it works smoothly but when we kill the application or launch the application again after coming from the background the white screen is shown and the application seems to get freezes there after showing the splash screen.
What is the problem and how to resolve it?
I am a native developer in iOS so in the case of native iOS we have an app delegate method for handling the application while coming from background like:
[image]

```
  applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)
  applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)
```

Is anything similar to these in ionic please have some light on this issue.

Comment: did you get any log in console ? please check your console log i think from there you will get some hint whats going wrong on 2nd load.

Comment: after killling the application i cant get any log on xcode while relaunching from the simulator itslef

Comment: Try to get it from Device & Simulator log in Xcode -> Window -> Device and Simulator Log window

Comment: ok i shall try to let you know now :)

Comment: it showing empty window..

Comment: Please see the edited question with log window

Comment: is your simulator is running ?

Comment: Yes it is the simulator. I know i should connect the device. Is this issue happening because of the free provisioning profile that once killed the application the debugger get killed too?

Comment: same scenario in Device also all you can get that log ?